# How to create a line graph from multiple columns in streamlit and python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plotly, streamlit

I am trying to create python script with help of streamlit and pandas from a csv file that has weather data with the below columns:
time,temperature,pressure,humidity,lux,Oxi-kO,Red-kO,NH3-kO,P1,P2,P3

What I am trying to do is to be able to select:

1. Date range
2. Data set(s), a multiple selection of the columns temperature..P3

Until now I have:

```
import streamlit as st
import os
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

st.set_page_config(
    page_title = 'Real-Time Data Weather Dashboard',
    page_icon = '️',
    layout = 'wide'
)

st.title(" :bar_chart: Real-Time / Weather Data from Enviro+")
st.markdown('<style>div.block-container{padding-top:1rem;}</style>', unsafe_allow_html=True)

fl = st.file_uploader(":file_folder: Upload a file", type=(["csv", "txt", "xlsx", "xls"]))
if fl is not None:
    filename = fl.name
    st.write(filename)
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding="ISO-8859-1")
else:
    os.chdir(r"C:\WeatherData")
    df = pd.read_csv("WeatherData.csv", encoding="ISO-8859-1")

list_of_column_names = list(df.columns)

col1, col2 = st.columns((2))
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"])

# Getting the min and max date
startDate = pd.to_datetime(df["time"]).min()
endDate = pd.to_datetime(df["time"]).max()

with col1:
    date1 = pd.to_datetime(st.date_input("Start Date", startDate))

with col2:
    date2 = pd.to_datetime(st.date_input("End Date", endDate))

df = df[(df["time"] >= date1) & (df["time"] <= date2)].copy()

st.sidebar.header("Choose your filter: ")

# Create for Data sets
data_set = st.sidebar.multiselect("Pick your data set", df.columns[1:])
if not data_set:
    df2 = df.copy()
else:
    df2 = df[data_set]
```

But I can't figure out how create a line graph the data set of the selected date range and e.g. temperature. One step further if I could combine in the graph for the same date range also the other columns depending on what has the use selected.

How can I achieve this?

Example of csv data set (delimenter is ','):

```
time,temperature,pressure,humidity,lux,Oxi-kO,Red-kO,NH3-kO,P1,P2,P3
2023-12-12 17:22:00.218,25.08,101330.98,33.52,18.62,11.32,266.51,263.17,11,15,15
2023-12-12 17:22:10.697,25.04,101329.69,33.58,18.62,12.90,269.93,338.87,11,13,13
2023-12-12 17:22:21.036,25.05,101327.94,33.52,18.62,14.48,269.93,374.77,13,15,15
2023-12-12 17:22:31.375,25.02,101330.41,33.65,18.62,15.71,268.21,393.64,13,15,16
2023-12-12 17:22:41.713,24.99,101331.40,33.75,18.62,16.73,266.51,403.70,12,15,16
2023-12-12 17:22:52.052,25.03,101329.48,33.70,18.62,17.60,266.51,414.23,12,15,16
2023-12-12 17:23:02.390,25.00,101329.97,33.77,18.62,18.31,266.51,417.85,11,14,14
```

What I have until now when running the streamlit app:
[image]

After the comment from [r-beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13107804/r-beginners) I updated some part:

```
# Create for Data sets
data_set = st.sidebar.multiselect("Pick your data set", df_cols)
if not data_set:
    data_set = [df_cols[0]]
    data_set.insert(0, "time")
    df2 = df[data_set]
else:
    data_set.insert(0, "time")
    df2 = df[data_set]

linechart = df2
fig2 = px.line(linechart, x="time", y=data_set, height=500, width=1000, template="gridon")
st.plotly_chart(fig2, use_container_width=True)
```

In case the user does not select any of the data set by default 'temperature' is shown in the graph.

Answer (score 1):

The column names in the sidebar alone are not enough to draw a graph, so time series data for the x-axis has been added as an option. Also, the graph side needs to deal with multiple column selections, so the y-axis specification has been made into a list. After the file has been loaded, the selection of column data and date selection is displayed using the file data. Functionalisation is easier to maintain when creating multiple graphs. The return value of the function can be used as `st.plotly_chart(fig,...)`. to.

```
import streamlit as st
import os
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

st.set_page_config(
    page_title="Real-Time Data Weather Dashboard", page_icon="", layout="wide"
)


def get_graph(df2):
    fig = px.line(df2, x="time", y=df2.columns[1:])
    return fig


def main():
    st.title(" :bar_chart: Real-Time / Weather Data from Enviro+")
    st.markdown(
        "<style>div.block-container{padding-top:1rem;}</style>", unsafe_allow_html=True
    )
    fl = st.file_uploader(
        ":file_folder: Upload a file", type=(["csv", "txt", "xlsx", "xls"])
    )
    if fl is not None:
        st.write(fl.name)
        df = pd.read_csv(fl.name, encoding="utf-8")
        df_cols = list(df.columns[1:])
        df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"])

        # Getting the min and max date
        startDate = df["time"].min()
        endDate = df["time"].max()

        col1, col2 = st.columns((2))

        with col1:
            date1 = pd.to_datetime(st.date_input("Start Date", startDate))

        with col2:
            date2 = pd.to_datetime(st.date_input("End Date", endDate))

        df = df[(df["time"] >= date1) & (df["time"] <= date2)].copy()
        # st.write("after filterd df", df)

        st.sidebar.header("Choose your filter: ")

        # Create for Data sets
        data_set = st.sidebar.multiselect("Pick your data set", df_cols)
        if not data_set:
            df2 = df.copy()
        else:
            data_set.insert(0, "time")
            df2 = df[data_set]

        # st.write(data_set)

        fig = get_graph(df2)

        st.plotly_chart(
            fig,
            use_container_width=False,
            theme="streamlit",
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! How would I need to change the `if not data_set:` in case the user does not select any thing to show all data in the graph by default?

Comment: Immediately after data has been loaded (with no data columns selected), the graph is displayed for all columns. If several data columns are selected and then deselected, the graph will be displayed for all columns. I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Maybe I was not very clear, see my updated version of the code for data set selection. Thanks